# What was the first fighter jet that utilised thrust vectoring nozzles?

Tags: jet, fighter

What is the first fighter jet that utilised thrust vectoring nozzles?

Comment: I would bet on some crazy Nazi design.

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_vectoring#Aircraft) *"A design for a jet incorporating thrust vectoring was submitted in 1949 to the British Air Ministry by Percy Walwyn. Official interest was curtailed when it was realised that the designer was a patient in a mental hospital."*

Comment: @RonBeyer That so needs to be an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hawker harrier... (actual plane that got used)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Siddeley_Harrier

Comment: This answer would be better if substantiated with links or sources.

Comment: absolutely... added link.

Comment: Although not a fighter, the prototype of the A-6 Intruder (YA2F-1) had tilting nozzles which were removed at some point after the flight testing had begun. There is a pretty nice photo of it in the A-6 Intruder article on Wikipedia, but for some reason I can't paste the link into the comment.

Comment: Surely this should be the Hawker Siddeley P.1127 / Kestrel ?